# Javascript - Combining Multiple Function Calls / Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Here is an example function fullScreen() that takes a div.holder and resizes it to match the viewport of the web browser.

```
function fullScreen()
{
    // Call to doSize() to resize the .holder when fullscreen() is first called
    doSize();

    // Call to doSize() on a window resize event
    $(window).resize(function(e) {
        doSize();
    });

    // doSize() - sets .holder to window viewport size
    function doSize()
    {
        $('.holder').width( bInfo.winWidth() ).height( bInfo.winHeight() );
    };
};
```

I've done things like this for awhile now, but I've always thought it looked weird to call doSize() twice inside of the fullscreen() function. The first time I call it is to start the action of resizing .holder when fullscreen() is first called, then I want to update .holder after that on a window.resize event.

Is there any way to more elegantly initiate a function like doSize() without having to declare it at the top of the function, and then again on a window.resize event? Or is this the only method of doing something like this? It seems crude to me, so I figured I'd see if anyone has improvements they could make or recommend.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for code review.

Answer (score 3):

```
function fullScreen() {
    var doSize = function() {
        $('.holder').width( bInfo.winWidth() ).height( bInfo.winHeight() );
    };

    // call it once
    doSize();

    // delegate to resize event
    $(window).resize(doSize);
};
```

Instead of calling the function twice, you just pass a reference to `doSize` directly to `$(window).resize()`. In your case there's no need to create another intermediary function.

Answer (score 3):

You should pass a reference to the `doSize` function itself as the handler, not an anonymous function that wraps the call.

If you don't want to declare `doSize` to be able to call it for initialisation, you just might want to trigger a `resize` event:

```
function fullScreen() {
    // Call to doSize() on a window resize event
    $(window).resize(function doSize(e) {
        // sets .holder to window viewport size
        $('.holder').width( bInfo.winWidth() ).height( bInfo.winHeight() );
    }).resize(); // trigger for initialisation
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this amounts to little more than a cosmetic change, but it sounds like what you're looking for:

```
function fullScreen()
{
    // Call to doSize() to resize the .holder when fullscreen() is first called
    // doSize(); // moved into assignment below

    // Call to doSize() on a window resize event
    $(window).resize( doSize() );

    // doSize() - sets .holder to window viewport size
    function doSize(){
        $('.holder').width( bInfo.winWidth() ).height( bInfo.winHeight() );
        return doSize; // allows executions to assign
    };
};
```

i don't see much cost to implement this, other than returning a normally-un-needed function instead of nothing, but that shouldn't take up very much extra time. you might want to modify the .resize() to use on() instead, and call off(doSize) before on(doSize()) so that calling fullScreen() more than once doesn't accumulate extra resize events.

Comment: wow, that just looks weird and confusing...

Comment: That *looks* just wrong (like the common newbie mistake), as it is not apparent that `doSize` returns a function.

Comment: i agree with you guys, but i couldn't find any other way not to invoke resize() twice as requested. i think it's clever, but i don't like clever. if you did it old-school instead of jq it's easy: ;(window.onresize=doSize)(); but again, too clever for my taste...

Answer (score -2):

what if you do not even wrap it in fullScreen()? Im assuming you have fullScreen() so you can call it when they click a button and then you have doSize() for when they resize their browser...

What if you just define doSize(), define a global variable called `fullScreen` and just pass doSize() to `$(window).resize()` anyway like you are doing.Then when they click your button, set `fullScreen = 1` AND call doSize(). The sweet part is when you define doSize() as:

```
$(window).resize(function(e) {
    doSize();
});    
function doSize()
{
    if(fullScreen===1){
        $('.holder').width( bInfo.winWidth() ).height( bInfo.winHeight() );
    }
    else{
        // return the div to default size
    }
};
```

This way when they initially enter fullscreen (from a button click Im assuming) the screen is resized automatically and only while `fullScreen=1` will the div be fulscreened and resized.

Just my .02. Hope this helps...

Comment: whaaaaat. why would I get down votes for this answer? i said its just my .02. there was no clear context given, so for the purpose of moving forward I made assumptions and gave an according answer